# Python If an item from a list is in a string, what is the item?

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

So let's say that I have a string:

```
some_string = raw_input('string')
```

And I have a list:

```
some_list = ['sacramento', 'los angeles', 'san diego', 'riverside']
```

Is there a way to check 1) If an item is from `some_list` is in `some_string` and 2) If so, what is the item?

I know that we could do something like the below:

```
divided = (some_string.split(' '))
for word in divided:
    if any(x in some_string for x in some_list:
        print word
```

But that would only work for items in the list which only has one word, and if I wrote `los angeles` or `san diego` for `some_string`, I wouldn't be able to find out what item is in the string with the code above.

So, in case you got confused, what I am asking is: If I have a string and a list, and the an item from the list is in the string, what is the item? I want to know a simple method that will work for any kind of list item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing too much work: don't split the input string.

```
for target in some_list:
    if target in some_string:
        print(target)
        break  # IFF you want to find only one match
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do:

```
if some_string in some_list:
    print(some_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this match for *single* or *multiple* inputs using **set** as well

```
list(set(some_string).intersection(set(some_list)))
```